Find the Max Number in the Column while fulfilling multiple criteria from 2 Ranges
My goal is for the formula to give me the maximum quote number based on certain conditions.  If the quote# column has a zero or blank and the Line Total column is greater than zero then the quote # should put out N/A. Otherwise, it should find the maximum number in the quote column.
For Example,
( Column 1-3) Maximum Quote#   2
( Column 4-6) Maximum Quote#  N/A



(1) Quote#
(2) Descr.
(3) Line Total
(4) Quote#
(5) Descr.
(6) Line Total




1
Bear
3
1
Bear
3


2
Dog
2
2
Dog
2


2
Bear
1
0 or blank
Dog
3


0
NA
0





2
Bear
0







=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B7:B15,0)+COUNTBLANK(B7:B15),COUNTIF(F7:F15,"\> 0"))," N/A ",MAX(B7:B15))
This has put out N/A if the quote number is 0 or blank and the line total is greater than 0. However, if I extend the range to the blank section it will still give N/A even though the quote # and line total is zero. It will not give me the max number until all  of the quote # in that column is filled.
=IF(AND((B7:B15=0),(F7:F15\> 0))," N/A ",MAX(B7:B15))
This will give out the highest quote number, but it did not consider the fact that there is a row without a quote # and a line total that is above zero. It should return N/A.
=MAXIFS(B7:B15,B7:B15, "\>0",F7:F15, "\>=0")
Same issue as the one above.

Would it not be logic to search the last non-blank in column B regardless the value in column F. I mean if it has a quote number it would have a value, right?

Yes, I agree with P.b. the simpler the logic, the better. It will help developers to implement it in a way that is most natural to your workflow. And you yourself can understand it within 5 seconds if the formula follows your logic directly.

what's unclear is whether these criteria must occur simultaneously or not (e.g. if line total = 0 for a particular row, but quote number = 2, must this return 'n/a'? I presume not because you've said "quote number =0/blank AND line total > 0".....

@P.b - not sure I would agree - human error / spotting errors / corrupt file/missing data.  By this argument we shouldn't really have missing quote numbers whenever Qty / value and line Total = 0 either (but in example we do, plausibly for same reasons)... Abundance of reasons why one would want to check this (to reconcile, to detect fraud, to .... etc.)

Apologies, I forgot to clarify. If the there is a quote number but the line total = 0 then the max quote  # should still give a value. It will not be N/A.

I hope I have understood you correctly.
Here is the formula you need:
=IF(OR(((B7:B15 = 0) + (B7:B15 = "")) * (F7:F15 > 0) > 0), "NA", MAX(B7:B15))
=(B7:B15=0)+(B7:B15="") returns a number greater than 0 if "Quote#" is zero or blank; if "Quote#" is neither zero nor blank, it returns 0.
=F7:F15 > 0 returns TRUE if "Line Total" is greater than 0; if "Line Total" is zero, it will return false.
=((B7:B15 = 0) + (B7:B15 = "")) * (F7:F15 > 0) returns a number greater than zero if "Quote#" is zero or blank but "Total Line" is greater than zero, otherwise, it returns zero.
=OR(((B7:B15 = 0) + (B7:B15 = "")) * (F7:F15 > 0) > 0) checks if there is any row where Quote# is zero or blank but "Line Total" is greater than zero.
If it returns true, result is "NA", otherwise, returns MAX(B7:B15).

note this simplifies directly to =IF(OR((-B7:B15=0)(G7:G15 > 0)),"NA", MAX(B7:B15)),(allowing for the correct column - G [vs F]).  i.e. -range = 0 whereever range is blank or 0....

@JB-007, thanks for the information. I always feel insecure when it comes to checking whether a cell is blank or zero or empty …

Here/screenshot(s) refer:
=IF(SUM(--(--B7:B15=0)*(G7:G15>0))>=1,"n/a",MAX(--B7:B15))



Testing other scenarios:

Error in row 6 since quote # blank/0 AND lineTot > 0


No error since quote # never blank/0...


No error here since when quote # blank/0 (row 7) lineTot = 0... (intersection of your criteria are not satisfied)
Ta,

Hi JB, curious to know why you're using -- in --Bxx:xx (I know why in SUM(--. Thanks.

This is so that blanks are returned as a 0 - I don't have to check both the condition of 0 and blank - I can simply throw -- in front and check 0s alone.  So - erm, "parsimony" if you're looking for a 'single-word' response.

Thanks, I get the same result (TRUE/FALSE) with or without the -- - that is in Microsoft 365; I don't know whether it is needed in older versions. That's why I was curious.

without the -- in front of the B44:b52 = 0 you would be comparing "" = 0 which would give a false when in fact you would want it to return a True for the set up here.  So you would get the opposite result without the -- when cell is blank.  The -- in front of the (--b44:b52=0)  i.e. --(--b44:b52) is probably unecessary since you'll be converting the to a 0/1 due to susequent operations.  without subsequent operations you wouldn't be returning a 0/1 for the sum to effectively yield the count of such instances... but this is the 365 compatible excel I'm using.

I prefer to use tables whenever possible (from your screenshot, it looks like you may be already using one). It makes reading formulas easy to read and maintain:


=MAX(FILTER(B7:B15,1-ISERR((1/B7:B15/F7:F15))))
1/B7:B15/F7:F15 creates an array of 1 divided by each cell in range B7:B15 followed by range F7:F15 if the cells contains a number it's row result will be a number, else, if any of the values don't contain a number value or 0, the row result would be an error.
Wrapping the array result in 1-ISERR() is the same as "not is error", which is used as a filter argument.
So all ID's where both the ID and Line Total contain a number not equal to 0 are filtered. Wrapping this result in MAX gives your final result.
Edit:
If you want to show #N/A in case the last entry of ID and Line Total do not match, you could use:
=LET(b,B7:B15,f,F7:F15,x,LAMBDA(y,XMATCH(0,IFERROR(y^0,0),-1)),IF(x(b)=x(f),MAX(b),NA()))

"if the quote number is 0 or blank AND the line total is greater than 0." per OP not satisfied. For instance, applying to table above will achieve exactly the same outcome observed by OP in final two examples of OQ (your function returns a value when it "should return N/A" in this case...

@JB-007 I think I got misled by the description. Added an edit.
